# Recursive function returns false instead of true

Tags: c#, .net

```
private bool AnyChildDomainExists(Domain parentDomain, int childDomainID)
{
    if (parentDomain.DomainID == childDomainID)
        return true;

    foreach(Domain domain in parentDomain.Domains)
    {
        return AnyChildDomainExists(domain, childDomainID);
    }

    return false;
}
```

For example this is my tree:

```
Root
  Child 1
     GrandChild 1
  Child 2
     GrandChild 2
```

I pass in the function `AnyChildDomainExists(root, GrandChild 2'sID)` it returns false. There is a small issue in the function but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: The function returns the results for the *first* child encountered. This means that when `GrandChild 1 `results in a `false`, the result will propagate all the way to the top, exiting all parent loops

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Exactly! How would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private bool AnyChildDomainExists(Domain parentDomain, int childDomainID)
{
    if (parentDomain.DomainID == childDomainID)
        return true;

    return parentDomain.Domains.Any(domain => AnyChildDomainExists(domain, childDomainID));

}
```

Check if any of the child domain Ids match, using LINQ [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to only return from the inner loop if the result is `true`. As it stands, you're returning a value on the first iteration of child domains, which is not what you want.

For example:

```
private bool AnyChildDomainExists(Domain parentDomain, int childDomainID)
{
    if (parentDomain.DomainID == childDomainID) return true;

    foreach(Domain domain in parentDomain.Domains)
    {
        if (AnyChildDomainExists(domain, childDomainID)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will only check the first branch

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is simpler than ORing. And it *does* check all branches. Checking for IDs 11, 22 returns `true`. Checking for `13` or `23` returns `false`

Comment: This is correct answer as well but marking Johnathan's answer as tick as it was answered previously. Thanks to Rufus

Comment: @RufusL yes I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

The way the loop is written, it returns the result from the first leaf node immediately and propagates it all the way to the top. This means that if `GrandChild 2` returns `false`.

One way to fix this is to `OR` the results of all children in the loop, eg :

```
private bool AnyChildDomainExists(Domain parentDomain, int childDomainID)
{
    if (parentDomain.DomainID == childDomainID)
        return true;

    bool result=false;
    foreach(Domain domain in parentDomain.Domains)
    {
        result|=AnyChildDomainExists(domain, childDomainID);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code will return `true` for node 22 (GrandChild 2) :

```
    var tree=new Domain(0,new[]{
        new Domain(1,new[]{
            new Domain(11,new Domain[0])
        }),
        new Domain(2,new[]{
            new Domain(22,new Domain[0])
        })
    });

    var found=AnyChildDomainExists(tree,22);
    Debug.Assert(found);
```

Comment: @RufusL it is, that's just the first thing that came to mind